# Python - Django - Pass Argument To Form Clean Method

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-validation

I am trying to pass a variable to a ModelForm clean method using `__init__` arguments but have had no success so far - I looked at various posts on StackOverflow but none seemed to help.

My code is the following:

```
forms.py

class property_booking_form(forms.ModelForm):
    check_in_date = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget)
    check_out_date = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget)

    class Meta:
        model = Properties_bookings
        fields = ['check_in_date', 'check_out_date']

    def __init__(self, property_id):
        self.property_id = property_id
        super(property_booking_form, self).__init__(self, property_id)

    def clean(self):
        check_in_date = self.cleaned_data.get('check_in_date')
        check_out_date = self.cleaned_data.get('check_out_date')
        property_min_nights = Properties.objects.get(id=self.property_id).property_minimum_nights
        ...

views.py

def view(request):
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        booking_form = property_booking_form(request.POST, property_id=property_id)
        if booking_form.is_valid():
            ...
    else:
        booking_form = property_booking_form(property_id=property_id)
    return render(...)
```

This raises the following error:
'property_booking_form' object has no attribute 'get'

Which seems to be related to the widget as per the error description:

Exception Location:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py in value_from_datadict, line 1058
```

The form works fine without the overriding `__init__`.

Does anyone know what would be the underlying cause of this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Please include the *full* traceback in your question, to make it clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `__init__` method should accept `*args` and `**kwargs`, you should pass these when you call the superclass' `__init__` method, rather than `self` and `property_id`.

```
def __init__(self, property_id, *args, **kwargs):
    self.property_id = property_id
    super(property_booking_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

You also need to change the way you instantiate the form in the view, since `property_id` is the first argument. For example:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    booking_form = property_booking_form(property_id=property_id, data=request.POST)
```

Alternatively, you can remove `property_id` from the signature, and pop it from kwargs. In this case, no changes to the views are required.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.property_id = kwargs.pop('property_id')
    super(property_booking_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Hi Alasdair, thanks for your answer. I have actually solved this using *args and **kwargs indeed. Although i did not need to pass property_id as an argument to the method. Please see below the exact code. Passing the property_id as an argument actually raised an error.

Comment: how would you then instantiate the form in order to make it work with your methodology?

Comment: I have actually found the reason why I had an issue when using the method you supplied. I mistakenly passed `property_id` after `request.POST` and therefore conflicted with the order of the positional arguments. If you want to edit your answer to include the change to `views.py` as well so the whole required changes are clear I can mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved by amending `__init__` as follows:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.property_id = kwargs.pop('property_id', None)
        super(property_booking_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Popping with `default=None` means that you won't  get a `KeyError` if you forget to instantiate the form with `property_id`. This might not be a good idea if `property_id` is required - you will delay the error until later e.g. when you run `Properties.objects.get(id=self.property_id)`.